# Distance travelled by a robot using Optical Flow

Tags: localization, opencv, robotics, opticalflow

is there a way to find out the distance travelled by a robot using Optical Flow? For example, using OpenCV, I'm able to find out the velocity of each pixel between 2 images taken by a camera. However, I don't know where to go with this to find out the corresponding distance travelled by the robot. Can you suggest a way to do this?

My main aim is to do the localization of the robot and for that I need the distance travelled by it between 2 instances.

Comment: You have already asked this question: [Finding distance travelled by robot using Optical Flow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069144/finding-distance-travelled-by-robot-using-optical-flow "title")

Comment: [Jacob's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069144/finding-distance-travelled-by-robot-using-optical-flow/3070004#3070004 "title") over on the previous question looks like the right solution path.

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly.  You can determine distance to objects, and then back calculate distance travelled from there, but it will likely be computationally expensive.

Answer (score 0):

What you are lookig is a SLAM (Simultaneous localisation and mapping) method, that is also used in with feature matching methods using SIFT SURF or FAST. 
Read e.g. [Quantitative Evaluation of Feature Extractors for Visual SLAM](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4058480)  for more information.