# augmented reality measure size of objects - feasability

Tags: android, image-processing, augmented-reality, measurement, feasibility

I want to develop an app on android to measure the size of objects in a room. E.g. to measure the length of an edge of a table. For this purpose I would use "edge detection" either from imagej or from openCV. Then I would take this edge and define the length of a small part of it as a reference. With this part it is perhaps possible to calculate the whole length of the edge. Perhaps the vanishing point can help me with calculations of the length here.

An example of what I roughly mean can be found here (at 1:19):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-19zSjggMZ0

The Questions:
1. Is there already an app like this?
2. Would you rather recommend imagej or openCV (I know a little bit about NDK and native functions)
3. It would be a project for a 3 month bachelor-thesis (means programming the stuff and in addition writing about 50 sites of text). What do you think about the feasibility concerning this fact AND feasibility in general?

Any thoughts (also beside my questions) are greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
gartenabfall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answer to this.

[How can I determine distance from an object in a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135116/how-can-i-determine-distance-from-an-object-in-a-video)

Comment: Thx for the hint. Any guesses about feasibility?

Comment: I suspect there are methods using parallax : move camera sideways, record video, extract frames to simulate two cameras separated by distance X. Then ?

There are a lot of applications for this, I'm keen to find a starting point, not strong enough of a coder to do all the heavy lifting but this would be an awesome project to make happen.

Answer (score 0):

I also used OpenCV heavily for my bachelors thesis.  I havent used imagej, but i can say that opencv is fast and easy to use (although i ran it on a PC).  As for your project, you will not be able to determine the length without some type of reference (eg the length from the camera to the object, or a known objects length).  what you could do is have a known reference, like a coin, appear in the image, then use that as a reference to determine length.

Comment: Thats what i meant with: "Then I would take this edge and define the length of a small part of it as a reference." I added "... as a reference." to make it clear. Thanks.