# Android OpenGL and Translation from Meters

Tags: android, opengl-es, distance, augmented-reality

I've been working with Android and OpenGL 2. I've been able to render objects in 3D space, and now I'm looking to work more towards AR. I want to be able to try to place objects relative to my current position, as if seeing it through my phone's display. I've been looking for resources on trying to map distances (in meters) so that it maps to what I'm rendering. (ex. I want to render something that looks to be 10m away from me directly facing forward, or 6m above me) I'm sure there isn't a simple solution and I haven't been able to find solid resources. Any recommendations on what I need to accomplish what I'm setting out to do? (At least to get started. I can elaborate if needed.)

Comment: You may want to check out the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135116/how-can-i-determine-distance-from-an-object-in-a-video

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose the scale of your virtual world yourself. You are absolutely free to choose whatever value you want. I.e. 1.0 OpenGL unit is equal to 1.0 meter. But keep in mind that you will have to design and texture your 3D models accordingly, so they look realistic in this scale.