# Cannot create custom message

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, feature-detection, surf, ros

Hi i am currently trying to create a custom message for an exisitng package however i create Point_id.msg but when i included it as a header file in my code, i receive the following error

```
/home/111/222/333/find_object_2d/src/objects_detected.cpp:7:41: fatal error:       
find_object_2d/PointObjects.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [find_object_2d/CMakeFiles/objects_detected.dir/src/objects_detected.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [find_object_2d/CMakeFiles/objects_detected.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

This is what i included in Point_id.msg :

```
int16 id
geometry_msgs/Point punto
```

This is my include header in the codes:

```
#include <find_object_2d/PointObjects.h>
#include <find_object_2d/Point_id.h
```

In the existing cmakelist.txt there was no sign of # rosbuild_gensrv()
so should i create a new package within the existing package and create the .msg files in the src folder and try to build it? or what should i do? i'm really confused.

Please help thank you!

Comment: @Mario can u take a look at this?

Comment: Using `@name` won't work unless the other person posted in that discussion. But sorry, no, never touched that code.

Comment: check @luator answer and this simple tutorial for more info: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the CMakeLists.txt of the package a bit, otherwise the *.h files will not be generated.

**If you use rosmake:**

Simply add `rosbuild_genmsg()` to CMakeLists.txt

**If you use catkin:**

With catkin it is a bit more complicated:

Add "message_generation" to `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...` and

```
add_message_files(
  FILES
  Point_id.msg
)
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  geometry_msgs
)
```

I hope, this helps.