# Computer vision google tango

Tags: google-project-tango, jmf

Tango is developed by google which has api that used for motion tracking on mobile devices. I was wondering if it could be applied to stand alone java application without android (for java-SE). If not then I was wondering are there any api out there are similar to tango where it tracks motion and depth perceptions.

I am trying to capture the motion data from a video, not camera/web cam. If this was possible at all.

Answer (score 4):

Googles Tango API is only **compatible with Tango enabled devices only**. So it does not work on all mobile devices only devices that are Tango enabled.  If you try to use the API with a device that is not Tango Enabled it wont work.

I think you should research a bit into **OpenCV** its an Open Source Computer Vision Library that is compatible with Java and many other languages.  It lets you analyze videos without the need for that many sensors (like Raw Depth Sensors which are primarily used on Tango enabled Devices).

Answer (score 2):

The Tango API is only available on Tango-enabled devices, which there aren't that many of. That being said, it is possible to create your own motion-tracking and depth-sensitive app with standard Java.

For motion-tracking all you need is a accelerometer and gyroscope, which most phones come equipped with nowadays as standard. All you basically then do is integrate those readings over time and you should have an idea of the device's position and orientation. Note that the accuracy will depend on your hardware and implementation, but be ready for it to be fairly inaccurate thanks to sensor drift and integration errors (see the answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97656/track-3d-position-with-an-accelerometer)).

Depth-perception is more complex and would depend on your hardware setup. I'd recommend you look into the excellent OpenCV library which has Java bindings for you already and make sure you have a good grasp on the basics of computer vision (calibration, camera matrix, pinhole model, etc.). The first two answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135116/how-can-i-determine-distance-from-an-object-in-a-video) SO question should get you started on how to go about determining depth using a single camera.